# Do not repeat conditions and variables in IFS

Tags: python

I'm starting in Python and I'm having problems. I'm creating a program with a menu and in that menu there are options, but the conditions are repeating themselves a lot in the IFS and every time I need to declare the variable in the IFS, is there a way to optimize this?

Ex:

```
If X == 1:
  A = int(input('...')
  B = int(input('...')
  C = int(input('...')
  D = int(input('...')
If X == 2:
  A = int(input('...')
  B = int(input('...')
  C = int(input('...')
  D = int(input('...')
If X == 3:
  A = int(input('...')
  B = int(input('...')
  C = int(input('...')
  D = int(input('...')
```

...

I have no idea how to improve the code. I tried Classes and objects but I'm still a beginner

Comment: Does the `'...'` text change depending on X?

Comment: what is IFS? is it an acronym?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a dict that stores the prompts for each value of `X`. For example,

```
prompts = {1: [...], 2: [...], ...}

A = int(input(prompts[X][0]))
B = int(input(prompts[X][1]))
C = int(input(prompts[X][2]))
D = int(input(prompts[X][3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Any reason not to do this?

```
If X in [1,2,3]:
  A = int(input('...')
  B = int(input('...')
  C = int(input('...')
  D = int(input('...')
```